# JavaScript get the last character's position of the string inside the other string

Tags: javascript

i guess the problem is extremely casual, but can't really find the solution.

i have a string

```
var full = 'hopaopGmailb3GkI'
var name = 'hopaop'
var service = 'Gmail'
```

**How do i get the `b3GkI` from the original string**, suppose the name and service are dynamic values also parsed from the string `var full`.

Or **how to get the index of the last character of the variable `service` inside of the `var full` string**

I need to get the index of the last character of the variable `service` inside of the `var full` string. `var index = full.indexOf(service);` returning the first character's index (6 in this example). Also for some reason i can't exclude name + service from the string.

Comment: var index = full.indexOf(service) + service.length

Comment: Upvoted @VladuIonut since it appears he commented before I submitted my answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1

```js
var full = 'hopaopGmailb3GkI';
var name = 'hopaop';
var service = 'Gmail';
var result = full.substring(full.indexOf(service) + service.length)
console.log(result);
```

Version 2

you can use [Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
var full = 'hopaopGmailb3GkI';
var name = 'hopaop';
var service = 'Gmail';
var result = full.split(service)[1];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`var index = full.indexOf(service) + service.length;` should do the trick. I also feel like you can come up with a regular expression to accomplish this, but I am no master.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative with Regular Expressions

```
var full = 'hopaopGmailb3GkI';
var service = 'Gmail';

console.log((function(source, service) {
    var match = new RegExp('(.+)' + service + '(.+)').exec(source);
    return {
        'service': service,
        'name': match[1],
        'token': match[2]
    };
})(full, service));
```

Returns an object like `{"service":"Gmail","name":"hopaop","token":"b3GkI"}`